# Show *realtime* mouse cursor coordinates? (Cursor mod / overlay) Also, copy to clipboard?

Tags: mouse, clipboard, cursor, location

I'm looking for a solution that would display the current mouse cursor coordinates **in realtime** (i.e. NOT xdotool and NOT xev).

I need to move the mouse to a certain position, then press Alt-Tab to flip to another window and record the coordinates there. (This would not move the mouse, so the coordinate display would stay the same).

There's a Windows program that works BEAUTIFULLY for this purpose - http://download.cnet.com/Cursor-Position/3000-2383_4-75449858.html?tag=mncol;1

...but it doesn't even start up in Wine.

Alternately, instead of displaying the coordinates, if this solution could copy the coordinates (in XXX,YYY format) to the clipboard, upon pressing a hotkey, that would be even better.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

P.S. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I don't know a program that do this specifically in Ubuntu. I would try luck into [unix.se] instead (if you do that, please delete this question, since they don't like crossposting).

Answer (score 8):

**Spartan solution**: you can show the coordinates in real-time with xdotool **if** you create a bash script. Just execute this in a new Terminal:

```
while true; do xdotool getmouselocation; sleep 0.2; clear; done
```

Change the value after sleep to make it more or less "real-time". This requires `bash`, the default user shell in Ubuntu.

**Better solution**: if you have admin rights, install `watch` (`sudo apt-get install watch`), and then execute this in a new Terminal:

```
watch -ptn 0 "xdotool getmouselocation"
```

It uses `xdotool` but does not require `bash`.

---

<sup>Thank you b_laoshi for your suggestion!</sup>

Comment: You can do this without a while loop if desired... `watch -n 0.1 xdotool getmouselocation`

Comment: Thank you! :-)
You can obtain a faster and precise result with: `watch -p -t -n 0 xdotool getmouselocation`. This has the advantage of being locale-agnostic and removes the unnecessary information.

Answer (score 2):

#### Get coordinates and copy to clipboard

Displaying the coordinates in real-time [has already been addressed](https://askubuntu.com/a/355443/606758), so I won't repeat that answer here. By creating a script and configuring a keyboard shortcut to run it, we can copy mouse coordinates to the clipboard in `x,y` format. Here's how:

1. Install xdotool for grabbing coordinates and xsel for managing the clipboard.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool xsel
   ```
2. Create a new script file with the following contents. Save the script and make it executable.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   xdotool getmouselocation | grep -oP "[0-9]+ y:[0-9]+" | sed 's/ y:/,/' | tr -d '\n' | xsel --clipboard
   ```
3. [Create a custom keyboard shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) that calls your script for the desired key combination.

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution to show the mouse pointer location, based on `xdotool getmouselocation` like the other answers, to display the location in its own xterm terminal:

```
xterm -geometry 9x1+0+0 +sb -sl 0 -T 'Mouse location' -e '
  set -e; tput civis; stty quit "^[";
  while true; do
    eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell) && printf "%4d %4d\r" $X $Y;
    sleep .05;
  done'
```

(this can be written on one line if need be).

Some explanations:

- The `-geometry 9x1+0+0` puts the terminal at the top left, with the expected size.
- The `+sb` tells xterm not to display a scrollbar.
- The `-sl 0` avoids an unnecessary scrolling buffer.
- The `tput civis` makes the cursor invisible (it would be annoying).
- The `stty quit "^["` allows one to quit with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd>.
- Concerning the `sleep` value, I find 0.1 too large; 0.05 seems OK.