# ScreenShot package with command lines

Tags: command-line

Ubuntu 18.04

I have been running Gnome-screenshot sometimes.  But I couldn't take a screenshot with a predefined pixel size.

I have been searching a while on Internet for command line screenshot package but I found many suggestions there.

Can any folk online sharing me his experience.  What I need is taking a screenshot with my required pixel size.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
SL

Comment: Do you want the area to be captured to have a certain height and width or do you want any image captured to be resized to a certain height and width?

Comment: Have you looked at [maim](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/maim.1.html)?

Comment: This can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/585455/

Comment: `maim --geometry=100x300-5+0 --delay=10 ~/Pictures/$(date +%s).png`. See maim's man page (link in my previous comment) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a command to capture a specific area of your desktop without having to subsequently crop the image.

For example, you want to capture a rectangle 500px wide and 300px high. And this rectangle is 200px from the left edge of your screen and 10px from the top of your screen.

You can do so with `maim` which can be installed with `sudo apt install maim`.

Assign a keyboard shortcut to the following code:

```
maim --geometry=500x300+200+10 ~/Pictures/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%S.png)
```

Now, each time you press the keyboard shortcut, an image of the specified size and position will be saved in `~/Pictures` with a timestamp and `.png` as the extension. (You can use the `jpeg` format if you prefer). Check [man maim](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/maim.1.html) for other options and visit the project's [homepage](https://github.com/naelstrof/maim) for more ideas.